# Python: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object when calling copy function

Tags: python, recursion, copy

I have a class *Particle* which has some parameters and attributes, as you can see below. But, when it does get to the function setter for position, and it executes the copy() function, I get the error message : *RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object*. I've tried different options, like *deepcopy()*, or *import sys sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)* , but none of them worked... Does anyone have any idea? This is my code:

```
def initCost(n):
    a = random.randint(0,10)              #gram.
    b = random.randint(0,5)             #price
    return [random.randint(0,a*b) for i in range(n)]

costs = initCost(10)

class Particle:
    def __init__(self, n, maxWeight):
        self.position = [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(n)]  #position
        self.velocity = [0 for i in range(n)]                    #velocity
        #self.fit = self.fitness(self.position)
        self.bp = self.position.copy()                           #best position
        self.bf = self.fit                                 #best fitness
        self.evaluate()

    def fit(self, x):
        fitt = 0
        for i in range(len(x)-1):
            if (x[i] == 1):
                fitt = fitt + costs[i]
        return fitt

    def evaluate(self):
        """ evaluates the particle """
        self.fitness = self.fit(self.position)

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self.position

    @property
    def bp(self):
        return self.bp

    @property
    def bf(self):
        return self.bf

    @position.setter
    def position(self, newPosition):
        self.position = newPosition.copy()
        #self.position = newPosition[:]
        self.evaluate()
        # automatic update of particle's memory
        if (self.fit<self.bf):
            self.bp = self.position
            self.bf  = self.fit
```

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Python's version of getters and setters, but I can tell you that the ones in your program are never called because the first thing you do when you instantiate an object of this class is to bind the `self.position` reference to a `list`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: No, they're called, and called again, and again...

Comment: @user2357112: cant you please tell me the mistake I'm making?

Comment: @user2357112 - Is there something about using properties with setters that prevents them from being masked by identical references?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: The "identical reference" goes through the setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `position` as the name of both the property and the ordinary attribute backing it. For example,

```
@position.setter
def position(self, newPosition):
    self.position = newPosition.copy()
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This attempt to set `self.position` will *use the setter you're defining*! Similarly,

```
@property
def position(self):
    return self.position
```

This getter just calls itself!

Trying to use `self.position` inside the `position` property definition won't bypass the property. If you want a "regular" attribute backing the property, call it something else, like `self._position` or something.